# I want to know how to stay logged in when running the app using firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Currently, I am experiencing the hassle of having to go through login authentication again when I log in and exit.

The existing Firebase login method seems to have changed a lot of information, so it is also difficult to access.

***loginpage***

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:aciel_pro/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final _codeController = TextEditingController();

  Future<bool> loginUser(String phone, BuildContext context) async{
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phone,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async{
          Navigator.of(context).pop();

          AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

          FirebaseUser user = result.user;

          if(user != null){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => HomeScreen(user: user,)
            ));
          }else{
            print("Error");
          }

          //This callback would gets called when verification is done auto maticlly
        },
        verificationFailed: (AuthException exception){
          print(exception);
        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              barrierDismissible: false,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text("Give the code?"),
                  content: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        controller: _codeController,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Confirm"),
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      onPressed: () async{
                        final code = _codeController.text.trim();
                        AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: code);

                        AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

                        FirebaseUser user = result.user;

                        if(user != null){
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => HomeScreen(user: user,)
                          ));
                        }else{
                          print("Error");
                        }
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
          );
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null
    );
  }
```

***HomeScreen***

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aciel_pro/sidebar/sidebar_layout.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final FirebaseUser user;
  HomeScreen({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Custom Navigation Drawer Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

  class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
              scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
              primaryColor: Colors.white
          ),
          home: SideBarLayout(),
      );
    }
  }
```

I need help.

I will post if there are more difficult or understandable materials.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` on app launch, and either navigate to the Login screen, or your main screen depending on the result.

Comment: In your code, you would do _auth.currentUser(), but that's if you still want them to be on the Login page whether they're already logged in or not. You can call Firebase auth.instance from anywhere, including in your main method.

Comment: So how do you write code to write code on the home screen? Even if you try to refer to other people's writing, you can't find where to apply it using firebase.auth (). SetPersistence.